# Querying extended attributes in AD-LDS against userProxy Full object

Tags: active-directory, adlds

If I create a userProxyfull object in AD-LDS and want to include an attribute that exists in AD but I want to have a different value actually be stored in AD-LDS, is this possible? An example would be mail or objectGUID perhaps. So when I try to look up a user in AD-LDS who is represented by a userProxyfull object, will it return the mail from AD or the one I created for it in AD-LDS?

Answer (score 0):

`userProxyFull` objects are used to perform authentication against `AD` for external use, without hitting the AD directly from outside. Everything is stored in `ADLDS` and will be retrieved from there. The `ADLDS` and `AD` users are connected using `ObjectSid`. The user must be created in `AD` before it can be created in `ADLDS`. The `GUIDS` will also be different.